# Is that possible to use IF statement to get data from database and save it into String?

Tags: laravel, database, string, web

I want to get some record from `tbl_jadwal` and save it into string in my laravel.
This is my code,

```
$get_time = if (now()->isMonday()) {
            return DB::table('tbl_jadwal')->where('Hari', 'Senin')->value('Jadwal_masuk');
        } else if(now()->isSaturday()) { {
            return DB::table('tbl_jadwal')->where('Hari', 'Sabtu')->value('Jadwal_masuk');
        };

$time = $get_time;
```

but i got message syntax error, unexpected token "if", is there any other way to solve this problem ?

Comment: You can use a function with your statement inside.

Comment: You can not assign the if statement to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking you can do:

```
if (now()->isMonday()) {
    $get_time = DB::table('tbl_jadwal')->where('Hari', 'Senin')->value('Jadwal_masuk');
} else if(now()->isSaturday()) { {
    $get_time = DB::table('tbl_jadwal')->where('Hari', 'Sabtu')->value('Jadwal_masuk');
}
// Caution: $get_time may not be defined here
return $get_time??null;
```

You can also use `when`:

```
if (!now()->isSaturday() && !now()->isMonday()) { return null; }
    
return DB::table('tbl_jadwal')
  ->when(now()->isSaturday(), function ($q) { $q->where('Hari', 'Sabtu'); )
  ->when(now()->isMonday(), function ($q) { $q->where('Hari', 'Senin'); )
  ->value('Jadwal_masuk');
```

However carbon also supports localisation so you may be able to get `now()->dayName` to actually return the day name according to your locale.